# Accessing the external SQLite database with Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database in my sqlite Manager in that i have one table.
Now i want to access that table through my android code.
Is there any possible way to do that...
Please reply me....

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of extra work involved but it can be done to include modifying your primary key and changing some of your db structure.

This article talks you through all the steps in depth. 
http://zaman91.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/android-how-to-use-own-sqlite-database/

It might actually be easier to just create a new db and populate it.